# Update method of DataSet.xsd doesn't changed DataBase, Why?

Tags: dataset, dataset-designer

I made a DataSet.xds file with VS wizard. Select part of tables works properly. Now I want update a record from a table, I used codes below.

```
private void AuthorsTableAdapter(DataRow changedDataRow)
    {

            authorsTableAdapter adapter = new authorsTableAdapter();
            adapter.Update(changedDataRow);
    }
```

This code can change the record and I can see the changes in for example DataGridView, but when I check the DataBase file or restart the application I realize the record(s) doesn't changed! That Update method just changed records in memory not in DataBase file. Any solution?

Sorry for my English and many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the UpdateCommand property of the adapter populated?

Comment: All Select, Insert, Delete and Update commands are generated. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the DataSet and then make it again without set a copy of database file in project. When you set a copy of database file in project, in every new solution building that database file will copy again. That was the problem!